# Python script that pulls build information from Jenkins into an excel/database

Tags: python, database, excel, jenkins

I am searching for a way to export latest build information of components from jenkins into an excel or a database. I have to use this information from jenkins to prepare some reports very often, hence I want to avoid manual work. Is there a way to use python script that would pull required build details from jenkins? I am a newbie to jenkins and scripting languages and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is off topic for SO, however, have you taken a look at something like this: https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: yes I have gone through this and installed python-jenkins 0.4.10, but I did not find a way how to retrieve build information for a particular component as there are number of components whose data is intended to be exported. Or may be i am not running the script in a right way. could be pls guide me here

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can export it to excel, but there is an option to automatically dump build related information to a database though. Using [Audit to Database plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Audit+To+Database+Plugin) you can achieve it.

1. Prerequisites: A simple database installed (e.g. MySQL) in the machine.
2. Relevant JDBC connector installed
3. Install [Audit to Database plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Audit+To+Database+Plugin) and in Jenkins
4. In Jenkins global configurations page set up - establish database connectivity by selecting relevant connector
5. Once global setup is active, add post build action as "*Audit Job info to database*" in the jobs where you want build information to be captured/recorded.

As soon as the job's main action is complete, this post build action will trigger automatically and dumps build related information in the database created.